# Tool to sync bookmarks between devices in the local network

Tags: sync, bookmarks

I'm looking for a tool to sync my bookmarks locally, without uploading them to any website (like xmarks does.)

Example: i currently use [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword) to sync my logins/passwords. They are **not** uploaded to any website. The program simply syncs between devices (Mac OSX, iPad, Windows) on the local network, without the need of any remote server/database.

Now i'm looking for a tool that does (kind of) the same thing, for bookmarks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Mozilla Sync you can setup your own Sync server on the network - without accessing the internet.

This would sync all passwords and bookmarks, even history between different devices, including mobile devices.

Mode information here: 
http://docs.services.mozilla.com/howtos/run-sync.html

Please note that this is a multi-user environment which might be a large cannon if you just try to sync 1 user between 3 computers. However, if your family wants to use this, and you want to include mobile devices etc, this might be the thing for you.